# Is there, in Java, a HashSet with functionality like `BlockingQueue.drainTo`?

Tags: java, queue, hashset

I'd like a way to copy the content of a `HashSet` into a collection, while not blocking new inserts.

`BlockingQueue` has this functionality in the [`drainTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-) method.

How to do it with a `HashSet`? Thanks.

* I'm open to using "concurrent HashSet" structures like `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`.

Comment: Note that the JavaDoc `BlockingQueue.drainTo()` states: "Further, the behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is _modified_ while the operation is in progress." Inserts would be modifications in that scenario.

Comment: @Thomas, I think they mean the collection that's passed as a param to the `drainTo` method.

Comment: You're right, that's true. One other question: `drainTo()` would copy and remove elements, do you only want to copy?

Comment: I think this would be difficult to implement in a non-blocking way for a collection based on a hashtable. It would be easier to atomically swap the reference to the `HashSet` (e.g. using `atomicReference`) to another (empty) `HashSet`. Now you "just" have to ensure that noone else has references to your "old" set.

Comment: @Hulk, I think that in order to "ensure that no one else has references to your "old" set" a lock is required when on swapping the reference.

Comment: @Thomas, I'd like to remove as well - not just copy.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka you are right, a way of making the two steps of reading of the reference and executing the method on the wrapped set atomic would be required. So far, I have not yet come up with a lock-free solution to that one. Still, it could be done with something like a read-write lock, where the write lock is only needed for the swapping.

Comment: @Hulk, My thoughts exactly. Added an SO question on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482673/how-to-replace-a-concurrently-instance-without-losing-data

Answer (score 1):

How about a method like this:

```
public <T> int drainTo(Set<? extends T> source, Collection<T> target) {
    Iterator<? extends T> it = source.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        target.add(it.next());
        it.remove();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    set.add("1");
    set.add("2");
    set.add("3");

    new Thread(() -> {
        set.add("4");
        set.add("5");
    }).start();

    drainTo(set, list);

    // could print [1, 2, 3] , [1, 2, 3, 4], or [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    // since there's no guarantee that the thread finished putting all elements in yet 
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Considering the `Set` is some "`concurrent hashset`" like `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`, I think this would work...

Comment: @Hulk Whoops, thanks. I'd forgotten that `HashMap` iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`.